# How I can register function without parameter type in DWScript

Tags: dwscript

I want register into script some stream method.
For example

```
function Read(Self: TStream; var Buffer; Count: Longint): Longint;
```

But parametr "Buffer" does not have type(by dws). How can I register this kind of parametrs into Delphi Web Script? What need to write into TdwsParametr.DataType???

Comment: Why the Delphi tag? In Delphi you don't need to register functions.

Comment: Because DWS is delphi's script???

Comment: No it is not. It is something separate.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What is the context? Is this run time, design time, delphi side, script side? Same goes for your other current question. Put some more effort into describing the problem, so ppl don't have to ask for clarification.